# How to delete data from datastore using NDB query in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have data like this:

```
{
  "queryValue": "SELECT Name, Site, Phone, Type, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.profile.Name FROM Account",
  "SFDCUser_id": "0056F00000ALw6aQAD",
  "updated_at": "2018-11-18T07:26:24.954000",
  "id": "aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIZCxIMUXVlcnlIaXN0b3J5GICAgICAyOsKDA",
  "is_error": false,
  "nid": 6102564412063744,
  "date": "2018-11-18T07:26:24.954000",
  "created_at": "2018-11-18T07:26:24.954000"
}
```

And I am using id to delete specific record from datastore. My code is like this:

```
ndb.Key('id',id).delete()
```

But its not working right, I am new to python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you're not "building" the key properly. The key should be built using the entity kind and its ID/name (if you know it). From [Specifying your own key name](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#specifying_your_own_key_name):

> ```
> account.key = ndb.Key('Account', 'sandy@example.com')
>
> # You can also use the model class object itself, rather than its name,
> # to specify the entity's kind: 
> account.key = ndb.Key(Account, 'sandy@example.com')
> ```

But that example assumes `'sandy@example.com'` was specified to be the key's ID/name when the entity was created.

The entity you show appears to be of the `Account` kind (or at least that's what you queried for), not of an `id` kind. So you should build you key just like in the quoted example (their entity kind was also named `Account`).

Also it doesn't appear that specified entity IDs were used for your entity:

- the entity's `id` value looks like a key's `urlsafe` string:

  `"id": "aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIZCxIMUXVlcnlIaXN0b3J5GICAgICAyOsKDA"`
- there's a `nid` value which looks like a datastore [auto-generated numeric key ID](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#datastore-generate-id):

  `"nid": 6102564412063744`

If so then `nid` is actually your key ID, so you'd be building your key like this:

```
ndb.Key(Account, nid)
```

You could also use:

```
ndb.Key(urlsafe=id)
```

But if you actually have the entity, from the query results for example, you no longer need to build its key to perform the deletion, you can obtain the key directly from the entity and delete it like this:

```
for entity in ndb.query(...).fetch(...):
    entity.key.delete()
```

If you have multiple entities to delete it's more efficient to use `ndb.delete_multi()`, see [Deleting entities in bulk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Python_Deleting_entities_in_bulk).